# React Jest, Enzyme remove or hide Received part

Tags: enzyme, jestjs

I'm exploring tests for my React build and in general - all works as expected.
I have question about "Received" info part of test.

Do I really need whole info? Because it looks redundant.

For example I do simple checking for DOM elements and expect to have 1 and got 2 - I'm happy with this part, but how can I hide all those spaghetti?

[image]

Jest part of package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "enzyme",
      "jest-enzyme"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but `.find()` returns a `ShallowWrapper`, which is an object. If you wish to check its length, use `expect(wrapper.find(...).length).toBe(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do,

1. Check if the find elements exits like

   ```
   expect(wrapper.find(".testing-purposes").exists()).toBe(true);
   ```
2. Check the length of the return elements like

   ```
    expect(wrapper.find(".testing-purposes").length).toBe(2);
   ```

According to the **[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavelengthnumber)**:

> Use `.toHaveLength` to check that an object has a `.length` property
>   and it is set to a certain numeric value.
>
> This is especially useful for checking arrays or strings size.

which doesn't seem to be the case for you

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the whole shallow rendered. The toHaveLength hasn't worked consistently for me.

Try:

expect(wrapper.find(".testing-purposes").length).toBe(2);